# C# get and return data not being displayed right

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
public double Tax
{
    get 
    {
        if(isDE)
        {
            deTaxAmount = sellPrice - tradeAllowance;
            deTaxAmount = Math.Ceiling(deTaxAmount/100d) * 100;

            deTaxRounded = deTaxAmount * StateTax;
            deTaxRounded = Math.Ceiling(deTaxRounded);
            return deTaxRounded;
        }

        return TaxableAmount * StateTax;
    }
}
```

This is a snippet of code from my program that seems to be causing the problem. It calculates correctly and spits out the correct data to the rest of the calculator. The problem is I have a label from another class referencing to the value of Tax and for some reason it will only pick up the value from the second return and not the first. I can not figure out for the life of me why the label is using the second return and the calculations for my program are using the first return under the if statement. Please help. here is the label code from the other class. All my other labels work like this its just this label causing me problems.

```
labelTax.Text = calculator.Tax.ToString();
```

Comment: Where is `isDE` coming from?

Comment: Did you try putting the second return in the else statement?

Comment: @Tiramonium that would make no difference at all.

Comment: coming from a drop down box. Like I said my calculator will calculate correctly when IsDe = true. But for some reason this label will not grab the right value when referencing to Tax. It actually grabs the value from my second return but my calculation will use the first return and display the correct value at the end.

Comment: Then obviously `isDE == false` when you set the label text. Have you tried using breakpoints to see what is happening? If you don't know what those are, look it up, it's part of essential debugging skills that will let you figure out this bug by yourself.

Comment: @NickMesser You should at least provide the line where `isDE` is instantiated.

Comment: okay breakpoints are awesome and made this a lot easier. Thanks for that! So its like was mentioned before. When the label calls to the Tax isDE is false. I gotta figure out what is making it false. Weird it wont just pull a value after calculating but instead tried calculating something again. .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess `isDE` is a public boolean variable in your class, carrying a default false value. Calling public property 'Tax' will hence won't go inside `if` condition and always return `TaxableAmount * StateTax`.

I'd put a debug point at this `if` condition and double-check the same thing.

Comment: Im new to breakpoints and this figured it out for me. For some reason isDE was being set to false because I was debugging a long time ago. I use the program at work so it wont get touched for months until I find a problem and adding this new feature made this a problem. Thanks for the help. Breakpoints are awesome and I will use them in the future!